# In Bash programming. how to read exact number of bytes and not return when meeting '\n'?

Tags: bash

In Bash programming, I want to read exactly 10 bytes, but not return when meeting '\n'
    I know in Bash 4.x, there is -N option to fulfill this feature:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 6<>/dev/tcp/localhost/6666
read -r -N 10 -u 6
```

But how this is implementated when no -N options is provided: such as Bash 3.x version?
Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example with Bash 3.2:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.25(1)-release
$ cat file
0123
4567
89ab
cdef
$ read -r -n 8 -d $'\0' var < file
$ echo "$var"
0123
456
$
```

Comment: But I think if justify EOF is better, but I don't know how to indicate it: read -r -n 8 -d $'^D' var < file. Is this OK?

Comment: `-d` only considers the first character of its argument (which is why, I think, `-d ''` and `-d $'\0'` behave identically, as opposed to any type of special-case handling).

Comment: I did not realize `-d` only take the first char. Removed my previous comment.

Comment: Still there's no such an `EOF` char. So be careful and choose a good `-d` delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick:

```
dd ibs=10 count=1 <&6 2>/dev/null
```

since `head -c 10 <&6` is not supported on Solaris

Comment: Unfortunately , head command can't support "-c" option in My Solaris environment.

Comment: I came back with another alternative :)